# XRDP not showing taskbar or header, what's wrong?

Tags: 12.04

I recently started out with Ubuntu and I installed x-remote desktop connection. However, when i log into the session, i get the desktop background and a mouse, no task bar, no screen header.

the instructions I followed were on this website: 
http://www.ubuntututorials.com/remote-desktop-ubuntu-12-04-windows-7/

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

XRDP can't run Ubuntu 3d session  So you have either to use Ubuntu-2d as the default session wehn you connect via xrdp or you can choose other sessions such as gnome-fallback, cinamon or whatever.

Anyway, to do that just edit/create `.xsession` For example to make ubuntu-2d as default session do the following:

```
cd /home/youruser
echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .xsession
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```